# R function for creating centerline of polygon

Tags: r, gis

Is there an R function to create a centerline of a polygon? Similar to these methods in [ArcGIS](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012414) and [Python](https://centerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Here's code to generate a dummy polygon -- where for this simple example we'd basically just want a line down the middle.

```
library(rgeos)
sdf <- data.frame(id=1:10, lat = 1:10, lon=1)
coordinates(sdf) <- ~lon+lat
sdf <- gBuffer(sdf, width=2, byid=F)
```

[image: dummy polygon]

Comment: I actually didn't find anything from a first look. You could try looking at the Python source of that package and copying some logic; it seems to rely on the Voronoi tessellation which you can do in R with (for example, there are others) `sf::st_voronoi`